# codeigniter how to use the alternative database connection in form validation using unique rule

Tags: codeigniter

i'm a newbie with codeigniter

i create an application using codeigniter and i use multiple database connection 
say:

database1 (default)

database2

when is use a form_validation library using the is_unique rule which require [table_name.column_name]

ex :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rule('form_field', 'alias', is_unique[target_table.column_name]);
```

the problem:
i want to validate the input form filed against database2,
however i use this code in the constructor

```
$this->database2 = $ci->load->database('database2', true);
```

> codeigniter error  Error Number: 1146 Table 'database1.target_table'
>   doesn't exist

where the target_table exist in database2

help me please

Comment: Try to re-assign the default db connection `$this->db = $ci->load->database('database2', true);`

Comment: thank you _Alexander Popov_, it works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method would be:

```
$DB2 = $this->load->database('database2', TRUE);
```

This now makes "$DB1" the variable which contains your database settings to run active record queries:

```
$DB2->query();
$DB2->result();
```

etc...

====================

Also, if both databases are on the same server with the same login etc, you could use this optional parameter:

```
$this->db->db_select('database2');
```